# Can't get @media queries to work in order to resize font on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I've made a simply and fun website a few days ago, but I can't make the text to resize on mobile devices. Here's what I have tried so far:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:320px)  { .output{font-size:0.5em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:768px)  { .output{font-size:0.8em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) { .output{font-size:1em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:1900px) { .output{font-size:1.5em;} }
```

I'm also using:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Please don't use `maximum-scale=1`...it's not recommended and offers very poor user experience if people can't zoom in.

Comment: Ok Paulie, thanks. I removed that, however I still cant get the text to resize .

Comment: **Mr EpK -** Try with adding **"max-width"** so that every device comes to an restriction.  
Also you can give it a try with adding **"max-device-width"** and **"min-device-width"** instead of the **"max-width"** or **"min-width"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On looking that sitem it looks like the div actually has an **ID** of `output`...not a class

So...

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px)  { #output{font-size:0.5em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:768px)  { #output{font-size:0.8em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) { #output{font-size:1em;  } }
@media only screen and (min-width:1900px) { #output{font-size:1.5em;} }
```

would be correct.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Can't believe I didn't figure that out lol.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're targeting a class instead of an ID in your media queries.  You div is `<div id="output>` so you need to target the ID 'output':

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px)  { #output{font-size:0.5em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:768px)  { #output{font-size:0.8em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) { #output{font-size:1em;} }
@media only screen and (min-width:1900px) { #output{font-size:1.5em;} }
```